# Use ggplot2 to plot single row where columns are horizontal variable

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data that looks like:

```
Name     Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4   Year5
Alpha    15      17      19      21      20
Beta     10      NA      NA      NA      NA
Charlie  2       4       3       6       7
Delta    6       2       9       10      11
```

My primary question is how can I use ggplot2 to plot `Alpha` as a connected scatterplot? I envision vertical axis ranging from 0 to, say, 25. And the horizontal axis being `Year1`, `Year2`, ..., `Year5`.

My secondary question is how can I also add `Beta`, `Charlie`, and `Delta` as their own connected lines - and how can I make them their own colors and have a legend denoting which is which?

In my real dataset (this here is just a toy example), I have over a thousand rows, so I may also somehow want to group rows if possible or do something to better help with visualization.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll probably need to `reshape2::melt()` it first.

Comment: That helps a lot. I was able to melt the data.frame and then do something like this: `ggplot(data, aes(variable, value))+geom_point(alpha=1/4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First melt your data as previously stated in the comments.
After that you want to scatter your observations with geom_point() and connect them by geom_line() while stratifying on the names (color = Name).

The theme options also allow you to modify the graph/text in the way you want it.

```
ggplot(basedata, aes(data, y = value, color = Name)) +
geom_point() + geom_line() +
labs(title = "Your title")+ 
labs(x = "Years", y = "Observation") +
theme_bw() + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2),face="bold"),
axis.text=element_text(size=12),
xis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) +
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Year 1","Year 2", "Year 3", "Year 4", "Year 5"))
```